# How to upgrade dev dependencies in Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I upgrade my Flutter `dev_dependencies`? The `flutter pub upgrade` command doesn't seem to work on those and I don't see a `--dev` parameter for the command so do I have to update them manually or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Recheck with the flutter sdk installation.

Comment: @krishna_tandon You mean like `flutter upgrade`? I've tried that

Comment: What error you are getting? I hope the path is correct. Are you able to create a sample project ? Are you getting the default sample project screen on emulator / device?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, I just want to update my `dev_dependencies` via a command for my existing project

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the carat syntax? (e.g., dependency: ^x.y.z)

[Carat Syntax](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax) documentation

Essentially, the carat indicates to automatically get the most up to date version of that package that is backward compatible with the number you specify. So it will update automatically up to a major version, at which point you will need to manually specify the new version number.

Comment: Yes, I know how it works. One of my dependency's versions is 1.6.0 and I'm trying to upgrade it to 1.7.0. In my `pubspec.yaml`, I have it set to ^1.6.0 under `dev_dependencies`

Comment: `flutter pub upgrade` doesn't seem to update it in `pubspec.lock`